# NetSuite API CustomerSearchAdvanced Column Custom Fields

Tags: netsuite

I'm trying to build a request which queries a list of customers from NetSuite and returns only the entityId, altName and one custom field which relates to the on-hold status.

The result should be a list of customers with the Id, Name and On-Hold status.

I am using the method: CustomerSearchAdvanced

Here is my request:

```
{
  "columns": {
    "basic": {
      "entityId": [
        {}
      ],
      "altName": [
        {}
      ],
       "customFieldList": [
        {
          "internalId": "2595",
          "scriptId": "custentity_client_status",
          "_typeName": "SearchColumnSelectCustomField"          
        }
      ],
    },
    "_typeName": "CustomerSearchAdvanced"
  }
}
```

This is an example of one of the records returned in the response:

```
"basic": {
        "altName": [
          {
            "searchValue": "Test",
            "_typeName": "SearchColumnStringField"
          }
        ],
        "entityId": [
          {
            "searchValue": "0",
            "_typeName": "SearchColumnStringField"
          }
        ],
        "customFieldList": [
          {
            "searchValue": {
              "internalId": "9",
              "typeId": "352"
            },
            "internalId": "2595",
            "scriptId": "custentity_client_status",
            "_typeName": "SearchColumnSelectCustomField"
          }
        ],
        "_typeName": "CustomerSearchRowBasic"
      },
      "_typeName": "CustomerSearchRow"
    },
```

The entityId and altName are returning as I expect them to however the custom field is missing the name which relates to the internalId.

This is what I want the search value field to look like:

```
"searchValue": {
   "name": "On Hold",
   "internalId": "4",
   "typeId": "352"
}
```

Is this possible?